# Pytesseract - Bad Results

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I a trying to crack an antibot in a web-based game I am playing.
I have written a bot in Python / Selenium, and now I'm trying to write a "crack antibot" function.

I have taken screenshot of the antibot (because the antibot is a php-file which change on reload).

Here is four different pictures of the antibot:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Here is my code:

```
output = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open('ab1.png').convert("RGB"))
output2 = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open('ab2.png').convert("RGB"))
output3 = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open('ab3.png').convert("RGB"))
output4 = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open('ab4.png').convert("RGB"))
print (output, output2, output3, output4)
```

And the output:

```
i A
```

Is there any way to get bet better results usng Tesseract? 
Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: You're gonna need to pre-process the image before passing it to tesseract, ideally the text should be black on white background. https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality
Alternatively, you could try Google Vision for OCR.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test1():
    # Grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
    filename = ("teu.png")
    image = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1,1), 0)
    kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.float32)/25
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, blur, iterations=1)

    # Perform text extraction
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(opening, lang='eng', config='--psm 13')
    print(data)

    cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
    #cv2.imwrite(filename, opening)
    cv2.waitKey()

test1()
```

Ok, so I have come so far. The text in black on white background.
But how do I shapren the text som it becomes more readable?

The output looks like this:

[image]